# I can't get this header working in a HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email, mailchimp

I'm trying to make a template on MailChimp, but I can't style it properly. There are a few caveats though: the CSS styles have to be in-line and it has to be structured as `<table>` tags.

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyGZ6.png)

[This is the end-goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6nT8.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
  <section id="header" style="background-color: #148e97;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="emailHeader">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="">
                          <div class="socialMediaIcons">
                            <img src="img/facebook.png"/>
                            <img src="img/twitter.png"/>
                            <img src="img/mail.png"/>
                            <img src="img/linkedin.png"/>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="title" width="500">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="">
                        <img src="img/logo.png"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="">
                      <h1 style="text-align: right; "
                    style="font-family: arial;">Brand USA E-News -- April 2016</h1>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
```

Comment: Why is it in tables? - Also what is your CSS?

Comment: @Andrew tables is the only way to realistically style HTML emails. That and inline styling... hence there should be no CSS style sheet, it should all be inline `style` tags

Comment: To the OP, you may benefit from removing any HTML5 symantics (`section`) from your code, as email HTML is something that is stuck way back in the HTML version 3 or version 4.0 at best.

Comment: Why are you using a `section` then?

Comment: You have two `<table>` tags set to 500 and 600 pixels wide. That's a total width of 1100px inside a single `<td>` tag when most HTML emails are typically designed to be 600px wide (or thereabouts). You need to use nested tables to achieve the layout you're after, and you need to be very precise on the width for the `<table>` and `<td>` widths.

Comment: @KirkBeard you should put that in an answer ;-)

Comment: @Martin I'm working on it now. I just wasn't sure I wanted to descend into the hell of HTML emails.. it brings back painful memories.

Comment: @KirkBeard oh I understand all too well, hence I've resisted to reply myself :-D

Comment: If this is your first eflyer - your best approach, is to download a mail chimp template and adapt it's basic structure to fit your needs. You can use CSS, if you pass it through this: https://inliner.cm/ before you upload. - HTML emails are painful!

Comment: @Andrew The mailchimp guidelines say to style everything using tables (not sure why though). and i've been using sections because it helps me lay it out better in my head but I think youre right and I should just go back and keep it to just tables.

Comment: Emails should be in tables as its runs on an older version of HTML. You are trying to style your tables like a `div`. You need to learn a bit of table styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating HTML emails, you need to transport yourself back in time, to a time when Internet Explorer 6 was cool.

You cannot use `<section id="header">` or `class="socialMediaIcons"` because not all email clients support the `<style>` tag. HTML5 elements are most unsupported, and your CSS needs to be inlined and used with the `style="..."` attribute. There's a lot of [mixed support for CSS](http://campaignmonitor.com/css) in email clients, so you're forced to cater for the lowest common denominator.

The following code gives you a *starting* point for how to create your layout:

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding:0">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#fff">
            <tr>
                <td valign="center">
                    <div style="background-color: #148e97; width:660px; margin:auto;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="660" bgcolor="#148e97">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="30">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1x1" width="30" alt="Spacer">
                                </td>
                                <td width="130">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x115" alt="Logo">
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" width="500">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="500">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1x1" width="1" height="20" alt="Spacer">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <div class="socialMediaIcons">
                                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/24" alt="Social Icon" width="24" height="24" />
                                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/24" alt="Social Icon" width="24" height="24" />
                                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/24" alt="Social Icon" width="24" height="24" />
                                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/24" alt="Social Icon" width="24" height="24" />
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <h1 style="text-align: right; font-family: arial; color: #fff;">Brand USA E-News -- April 2016</h1>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="30"><img src="http://placehold.it/1x1" width="30" alt="Spacer"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

One thing you'll notice is there are a lot of `<table>` tags in other `<table>` tags inside even more `<table>` tags. Things get messy.

I've used the old school technique of `spacer.gif` (using `http://placehold.it/1x1` in lieu of a 1x1.gif image), which is no longer needed these days when building *websites*.

Hopefully this code sets you on the right path. I haven't built HTML emails for 5+ years, so I'm a little rusty.

Comment: Good answer. The thing is you havn't built HTML emails for 5 years, but in that five years *nothing has changed for HTML emails*! Every other part of the internet seems to develop, except emails....

Comment: Thank you very much Kirk, this really helps me understanding the craziness of table inception haha.

Comment: @GabrielRivera Table Inception is a good way of thinking about it. I once had to work around a bug with earlier versions of Lotus Notes when I hit the limit for how many nested `<table>` tags I could use. [Hint: 10 nested `<table>` tags](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2009/01/nested-tables-in-email-how-much-is-too-much/)  is the limit.

Comment: @GabrielRivera if this solves your issue you can click the tick next to this answer to indicate it's the right answer. :-)

Comment: @Martin thank you indeed for the reminder, Ill be sure to do it. and thanks everyone for the help!